# no entiendo el cannot read property addEventListener

Tags: javascript

lo que pasa es que, al yo pasar el codigo me dice que no puede ser leída esa propiedad porque es nula, pero al hacer la depuración descubrí que el null era la variable, ya que probado mas de 10 variables diferentes y no funciona, agradecería si me pueden ayudar

```js
'use strict'
function Color(){
  console.log("ok");
  var bg=boton.style.background
 if(bg == "yellow"){
  bg=boton.style.background="blue";
 }
 else{
  bg=boton.style.background="yellow";
 
 }
 
  return true;
}
// click
var boton=document.querySelector("#boton");
 boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  Color();
 });
//mouse over
boton.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  var mo=boton.style.background
  if(mo=="white")
   mo=boton.style.background=("pink");
  
 });
//mouse out
boton.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  var mu=boton.style.background
  if(mu=="pink")
   mu=boton.style.background=("white");
  
 });
boton.style.background=("white");
//focus
var tetero=document.querySelector("#NM");
 debugger
 tetero.addEventListener("focus",function(){
  console.log("profin");
 });
```

Comment: Tu codigo no tiene ningun problema.  Quizas aguno de los ID's no existe.

Comment: agrega a tu html el boton , algo como `<button id="boton">tu boton</button>`hice una prueba y el boton me funciono

Answer (score 1):

Se podría decir que error ocurre porque el código está incompleto, en específico, los `querySelector` no encuentran los elementos con id `boton` y `NM` por lo cual devuelven `null` y null no tiene una propiedad llamada `addEventListener`

Agregando estos elementos en el HTML funciona. Ejemplo:

```js
'use strict'
function Color(){
  console.log("ok");
  var bg=boton.style.background
 if(bg == "yellow"){
  bg=boton.style.background="blue";
 }
 else{
  bg=boton.style.background="yellow";
 
 }
 
  return true;
}
// click
var boton=document.querySelector("#boton");
 boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  Color();
 });
//mouse over
boton.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  var mo=boton.style.background
  if(mo=="white")
   mo=boton.style.background=("pink");
  
 });
//mouse out
boton.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  var mu=boton.style.background
  if(mu=="pink")
   mu=boton.style.background=("white");
  
 });
boton.style.background=("white");
//focus
var tetero=document.querySelector("#NM");
 debugger
 tetero.addEventListener("focus",function(){
  console.log("profin");
 });
```

```html
<button id="boton">Color</button>
<input id="NM">
```